# Represent HashMap in class diagram

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, uml, class-diagram

I have a class diagram which has a dictionary (in python terms) as an attribute. This is the basic structure:

```
serverEntry = { creditCardObj1 : accountBalance1, creditCardobj2 : accountBalance2, ...}
```

To clarify, creditCardObj1 is an instance of a class CreditCard while accountBalance1 is an integer value and similarly for the other entries in the dictionary.

I read that in Java, it is called HashMap. In any case, I would like to implement it in my UML class diagram. Any tips on how to do that. I am using Visio 2007 so it would even more helpful if someone can explain in terms of that.

Comment: You may not get a notification of my new answer unless I put a comment here. Please see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't put much effort into this, as another answer has been chosen already. That answer does not cover the closest thing in UML to a HashMap: the *qualifier*. It is drawn as a rectangle between a class and an association. Inside the rectangle is a name and a type. What it means is that given an instance of that type, the association will yield some number of instances of things on the other end of the association. That number of instances is specified with a multiplicity.

For your purposes, you would put `creditCard: CreditCard` inside the qualifier rectangle, and `Integer` on the other end of the association, with a multiplicity of `1`.

Comment: I can't delete my answer. SO does not permit to delete an accepted answer. I just was not aware of qualifiers and had not been using them (still I rarely use them). So the above was more sort of a work around.

Comment: @qwerty_so: thank you. If you feel strongly, adding a comment to the original question may influence the person who made the decision.

Comment: He's been noticed about these comments. Let's see. Some people are here only sporadically.

Comment: Last active 2017... Funny, he's also a guitar player (me too until I had an accident with my left hand).

Comment: I called the mods (for the first time).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question is more about UML than about the programming language. Thus, please allow me to use the language I feel more comfortable in.

C# calls it Dictionary too, `Dictionary<string, T>` for example with a `string` for the **HashKey**. The UML Class Diagram in Visual Studio (I am using the Community Edition of VS 2015 here) is fortunately close enough to code so that the UML Model basically is the language's meta-model and the diagram is just a different view to the real code.

This comes in handy because real programming problems - like the one you asked for - can be addressed directly in the diagram. (Also: no extra code generation or additional parsing necessary to get or maintain the diagram).

I like the way Visual Studio solved this. They offer two options, one that is focussed more on the technicalities (`show as Association`)

[image]

and one that is focussed more on the domain (`show as Collection Association`).

[image: Show as Association]

I am usually using the first one only if I need the diagram to emphasize that the `Dictionary` class is involved, in every other case the second option is my preferred option.

Comment: Mickeysoft is using it's own flavor of UML. Why use a standard if I can make my own?

Comment: That's like asking why use OpenAPI specs if I can make my own specs?